# How to bind SWIFTUI Button action to viewmodel action or method

Tags: ios, swiftui, two-way-binding

I am trying to bind swiftui button action and getting the error like `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<() -> ()>' to expected argument type '() -> Void'`

In View

```
Button(action : $viewModel.action ) {
                        Text("Login")
                    }
```

In ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var userid = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var selection : Int? = 0
    //@Published var action : () -> void = {}
    func action()  {
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need binding in Button action,

```
Button(action : viewModel.action ) {     // << no $ here !!
                        Text("Login")
                    }
```

everything else should be fine.